# Beamer title element

Tags: beamer, titles

I am creating my own custom .tex beamer template. I have issues customizing the title.

I insert the title within the `\defbeamertemplate*{title page}` command, and this is supposed to be overlayed on a tikz picture (defined in `\setbeamertemplate{background}`).

Now, this is what I cannot fix (and it's a lot, I'm sorry):

I would like the text box to be "anchored" to the south west, so that if the title has several lines, the box expands north without writing over the author's name. 
I would like the font to be ridiculously large, and that the underline "width" is large as well. I would also like to change the line spacing to 1cm, but only for the title. 
Finally for line breaks, I would appreciate if it were automatic (right now the user has to manually enter a linebreak where needed, otherwise it overflows east)

Here is a MWE:
beamerthemeMWE.sty

```
\RequirePackage{tikz, xcolor, textpos, fontawesome, adjustbox,ulem}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, matrix}

    \usepackage{helvet}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \renewcommand*\ttdefault{\sfdefault}

    \setbeamerfont{title}{size=\fontsize{33.3}{60}}
    \setbeamerfont{author}{size=\fontsize{10}{55}}
    \setbeamerfont{normal text}{size=\fontsize{16}{20}}
    \AtBeginDocument{\usebeamerfont{normal text}}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{MWE}[1][]{
    \begin{textblock}{12}(0.35,0){
        \renewcommand{\ULthickness}{2.5pt}
        \uline{\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle}}
    \end{textblock}

    \begin{textblock}{200}(0.3,4.5)
        {\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor \\\vspace{-.25cm} \insertdate}
    \end{textblock}
}
```

example.tex

```
\documentclass[ aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetheme{MWE}   

\title{This is a title that,\\as you can see, behaves strangely}           
\date{\today}
\author{Michel TheMan}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}    
\end{document}
```

finally, here is the result
[image: This is the result]

I have no idea why the font changes at the linebreak, and before that I was not able to change the spacing between the two lines, nor the spacing between the text and the underline..

Comment: `\uline` is not intended to be used over multiple lines. There are, however, solutions for that problem, if you insist on using it.

Comment: Oh, thank you! It indeed solves the automatic line break and font size issues. However, I still cannot anchor it south west or control the line spacing.. Also, I would like the title to be underlined.

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need to load `xcolor` with beamer

Comment: Indeed, thank you as well. The clearer the better. @nox, thank you very much for the help. I made it work in the full example too. But damn, if it isn't sensible. Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't cleaned up the code entirely, and I put the definitions in the main file to play around with it more easily (I'll leave it to you, to separate it into a style file again).

What I do is put the title in a box, measure its height and depth, and use that for positioning. That way you can achieve your desired behavior:

> the text box to be "anchored" to the south west, so that if the title has several lines, the box expands north

Also, I used the `soul` package for underlining, as it features line breaks and more customization. Furthermore, I manipulate the `\baselineskip` manually. In general you should be very careful doing this, but here it should be alright.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz, xcolor, textpos, fontawesome, adjustbox}
\usepackage{soul}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, matrix}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{\sfdefault}

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\fontsize{33.3}{60}}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\fontsize{10}{55}}
\setbeamerfont{normal text}{size=\fontsize{16}{20}}
\AtBeginDocument{\usebeamerfont{normal text}}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{MWE}[1][]{%
  \sbox0{\hbox{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{% Here is the magic, save all in box 0
    \usebeamerfont{title}\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.3em}% manipulate \baselineskip manually
    \setul{.3ex}{2pt}% set underline depth to .3ex and line thickness to 2pt (soul package)
    \expandafter\ul\expandafter{\inserttitle}\par}}}
  \begin{textblock*}{\linewidth}(.3cm,\dimexpr50pt-\ht0-\dp0\relax)% Using height and depth of box 0
    \usebox0% put the content in here
  \end{textblock*}

  \begin{textblock}{200}(0.3,4.5)
    {\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor \\\vspace{-.25cm} \insertdate}
  \end{textblock}
}

\title{This is a title that,\\as you can see, behaves strangely}
\date{\today}
\author{Michel TheMan}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\title{This is a title}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```